# Problems installing R 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

Recently I had to update R from 3.4.4 to 3.5 for installing bioconductor packages. For doing that I followed the steps on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031597/r-3-5-0-for-ubuntu).

But now I have the problem that r studio do not work for the problem:

```
R shared library (/usr/local/lib/R/lib/libR.so) not found. If this is
a custom build of R, was it built with the --enable-R-shlib option?
```

For that reason I tried to reinstall R 3.4.4 with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

But it returns me this error:

```
 Reading package lists... Done

  Building dependency tree       

  Reading state information... Done

  Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have

  requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable

  distribution that some required packages have not yet been created

  or been moved out of Incoming.

  The following information may help to resolve the situation:

  The following packages have unmet dependencies:

   r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.1-2xenial) but it is not
 going to be installed

  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to remove completely R (3.5) and installing again the 3.4 version?

Thank you all.

Edit: R works on command line with the 3.5 version and I cannot install other packages like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
```

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 libgdal-dev : Depends: libarmadillo-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libdap-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgeotiff-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgif-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhdf4-alt-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhdf5-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libjpeg-dev
               Depends: libmysqlclient-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libnetcdf-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libpoppler-private-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libpq-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libtiff-dev
               Depends: libxml2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I like askubuntu as much as the next guy for Ubuntu question -- but for *R on Ubuntu* there are only two places: the README at https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html and the r-sig-debian mailing list.